# How to convert the Javacard cap file to its corresponding byte stream?

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

I'm currently developing Javacard and generate the cap file using Ant script(the file name be like demo.cap), and now I want to construct the GP(GlobalPlatform) command to run the LOAD process on a samrt card. But it's encapsulated into cap format. Is there any way I can convert the cap file to its corresponding btye stream so I can truncate it and construct the data field of GP LOAD command, just like the figure link shown below?
[Load File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keDyg.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "hex format" - at least not in the way that you are using the term. A hex or hexadecimal format would be indicating a way to show hex on the screen, such as `a1`, or `A1`, or `0xA1` (etc.).

What you see is the human *representation of bytes* using hexadecimals. So if you see `E2` then this is a byte with value `E2`, **or** `1110 0010` in binary, **or** 242 in decimals (assuming that it represents a positive number).

I strongly recommend understanding the difference between binary (bit / byte) values and their representation / encoding techniques before diving deeper into Java Card. Lookup a few tutorials and check the tags [encoding](/questions/tagged/encoding) (binary to text) and [character-encoding](/questions/tagged/character-encoding) (text to binary) on Stack Overflow.

All the conversion to/from those particular command and response APDU's will be performed by a GP library or application, such as [GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro) (Open Source in Java) or [GP Shell](https://kaoh.github.io/globalplatform/) (Open Source in C). Those libraries will just pick up the file and create the (usually encrypted) APDU's around them.
<sub>I have no affiliation with either project</sub>

When sending they *may* show the transmitted bytes as hexadecimals on your screen - if that kind of logging is enabled. The APDU's themselves are transmitted as *binary* - as opposed to text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I'm sorry for my incorrect expression. I know about the concept of hexadecimals and its relationship with binary. What I really want to know is the coversion from cap file to, maybe the byte stream,  so I can construct the command(APDU) by myself and send it to card. I've got a tool which can achieve this feature and the byte stream is stored in a plain text file. I want to know the conversion process but I don' have the src code. I want to develop a similar tool and that's why I ask this question.

Comment: Well, I did point to an Open Source repository didn't I? Why not contribute to that? There are plenty of libs that do GP, so if you are not in need of anything **special**, then we can do without one additional one-man show.

Comment: I got it. I just think it'll be better to know how it works. Thanks for your reply, I will go to view the src code of such kind of libs and learn more.

Comment: I've added an O/S Java lib, probably easier for a Java programmer, as you've indicated the [tag:java] tag for your question.

Comment: Thank you Maarten, I've heared of GP Pro before but do not read the code. Later I'll try to learn more about it. Thank you again for your patience and detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Maarten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73119749/5128464) kindly says -- have a look at GlobalPlatformPro, where [LOAD commands are built](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/blob/66427621fc84d010f31b11e4211b241d1999f07e/library/src/main/java/pro/javacard/gp/GPSession.java#L567) and its related project [CAPFile](https://github.com/martinpaljak/capfile/blob/eebade595c0896cc92186eff0b5c33107e14ce42/src/main/java/pro/javacard/CAPFile.java), where [data stream for load is constructed](https://github.com/martinpaljak/capfile/blob/eebade595c0896cc92186eff0b5c33107e14ce42/src/main/java/pro/javacard/CAPFile.java#L229).

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you vlp. I'll learn more about it!